# Warning: Each child should have a unique key - Passing Array In ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, key

I was practicing ReactJS tuts on Scrimba where you have to pass id props in array

```js
import React from 'react';
import Joke from './components/Joke.js'
import jokesData from './components/jokesData';

function App() {
  
  const jokeComponents = jokesData.map(function(joke) {
    return (
      <Joke 
        obj={{key: joke.id, question: joke.question, punchline: joke.punchLine}} 
      />
    )
  })

  return (
    <div>
      {jokeComponents}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Then I got a warning in console:

Warning log

[image: Warning log]

In the image above the key value was passed but I still got the warning message. I'm trying to pass the elements into a single object. Can anyone help me find the problem here?

Comment: `<Joke key={joke.id} ...>` (the warning says `key prop`, your Joke only has an `obj` prop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `key` attribute and pass in that `joke.id`.

```
  const jokeComponents = jokesData.map(function(joke) {
    return (
      <Joke 
        obj={{key: joke.id, question: joke.question, punchline: joke.punchLine}}
        key={joke.id)
      />
    )
  })
```

Comment: You should not use index for key.

Comment: Yeah, i have corrected it, i noticed he does have an id for the joke, so no need for index anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass key as prop to Joke component. id would be great choice because of how react reconciliation work.

```
<Joke  key={joke.id}
            obj={{key: joke.id, question: joke.question, punchline: joke.punchLine}} 
          />
```